# R: Spread Time Series Data Based on Event Time

Tags: r, time-series

I have a large time series dataset that currently iterates through the data to change the time series data into events divided by time interval. I am looking for something more slick than iterating through, because this gets pretty slow with how large my data is. My starting dataframe looks similar to this simple one:

```
structure(list(Name = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("a", 
"b", "c"), class = "factor"), datetime = structure(c(1597203000, 
1597201200, 1597199400, 1597186800, 1597185000, 1597183200, 1597197600, 
1597195800, 1597194000, 1597181400, 1597179600, 1597177800, 1597192200, 
1597190400, 1597188600, 1597176000, 1597174200, 1597172400), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = ""), percent = c(0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 
4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-18L))
```

The data is half-hourly, so if a `Name` variable has two consecutive half hourly `datetime` values, I consider it to be a part of the event. I would also give some leniency, so if the data doesn't show consecutive half hourly values, but there are consecutive hour values, that would work as well. So the goal is to return a dataframe that looks like so:

```
structure(list(Name = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("a", 
"b", "c"), class = "factor"), startdate = structure(c(1597203000, 
1597197600, 1597192200, 1597186800, 1597181400, 1597176000), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = ""), enddate = structure(c(1597199400, 1597194000, 
1597188600, 1597183200, 1597177800, 1597172400), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Thanks in advance for any snazzy solutions, I greatly appreciate it!

EDIT: The datetime values will not necessarily be in order going down the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what your looping looks like, but if you use the following code you can put the looping off until late making things run possibly a little faster at least.

```
df= with(df, df[order(Name, datetime),]) %>% 
         mutate(dftime = difftime(lead(datetime),datetime, units = "mins")) %>%
         mutate(eventnum = 0)

i = 1
j = 1
for(i in 1:length(df$eventnum)){
  if(df$dftime[i] <= 60){          # accounting for your consecutive hours comment
    df$eventnum[i] = j
  } else{df$eventnum[i] = j
         j = j + 1}
  i = i + 1
}
```

Then you could use a summarise sort of set up like akrun's answer he shared here like the following:

```
df_lengths = df %>% group_by(eventnum, Name) %>% 
                     summarise(startdate = first(datetime), enddate = last(datetime)) %>% 
                     ungroup %>% select(-eventnum)
```

But this is only a better answer assuming that you do the looping earlier in the data organization, for example if you loop through the time difference calculation as well as the interval checks.

Comment: This is faster than my looping, but I was hoping for something a little more slick than this. This works, but since I'm running this on a very large dataset I was hoping for something faster than this as well

Comment: Marking this as answered for now, but hopefully someone will share something quicker than this at some point.

Answer (score -1):

Create a grouping variable with `rleid` (from `data.table`) on the 'Name' column, then `summarise` the 'datetime' column by returning the `first` and `last` elements in two columns

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(grp = rleid(Name), Name) %>% 
   summarise(startdate = first(datetime), enddate = last(datetime)) %>%
   ungroup %>%
   select(-grp)
# A tibble: 6 x 3
#  Name  startdate           enddate            
#  <fct> <dttm>              <dttm>             
#1 a     2020-08-11 22:30:00 2020-08-11 21:30:00
#2 b     2020-08-11 21:00:00 2020-08-11 20:00:00
#3 c     2020-08-11 19:30:00 2020-08-11 18:30:00
#4 a     2020-08-11 18:00:00 2020-08-11 17:00:00
#5 b     2020-08-11 16:30:00 2020-08-11 15:30:00
#6 c     2020-08-11 15:00:00 2020-08-11 14:00:00
```

Comment: Does this assume that things will always be in a nice order going down the datetime? Because that's not necessarily the case. I'll edit the question to reflect that

Comment: @obewanjacobi I didn't see any change in the example

Comment: I edited the original dataframe to better reflect what I'm looking for. When you run your code on the first dataframe now, it only gives 1 time interval per `Name`